# Haskell: Copying a file

Tags: haskell, io, file-copying

I am trying to make a haskell program using I/O that prompts the user the filename and the name of the copy. This is my current code:

```
copyFile :: IO ()
copyFile = do 
 putStr "Enter the filename:" 
 name <- getLine 
 putStr "Enter the copy name:" 
 c_name <- getLine
 contents <- copyFile name
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
  contents <- copyFile name
    |
 73 |  contents <- copyFile name 
    |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any help please on what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You override it, by specifying your own `copyFile`, it should be `main`. But even then, the result of `copyFile` is not the content, the type is `FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 2):

You *define* a `copyFile` function, and then call the `copyFile` function (of `System.Directory` I assume?). So Haskell thinks you make a recursive call. We can thus rename the function to `main`.

But this will not fully solve the problem. [**`copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:copyFile) is a function that takes two `FilePath`s, and then copies it from the source to the destionation, so writing `contents <- copyFile name` is rather weird, since (1) it lacks a second parameter; and (2) the result is a `()`, so `contents has no sense here.

So we can fix it by writing:

```
import System.Directory(copyFile)

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    putStr "Enter the filename:" 
    name <- getLine 
    putStr "Enter the copy name:" 
    c_name <- getLine
    copyFile name c_name
```

Comment: Oh yes I see that I have used "copyFile" in a wrong way and I forget that it needs two parameters. Thanks for the clarification and help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're not actually using c_name.

Secondly, your issue is caused by the last line: `contents <- copyFile name` is equivelant to `copyFile name >>= \contents ->` which is using the monadic bind operation to pipe the result of `copyFile name` to another function. You don't actually do anything with the result and therefore it's not a complete expression.

Comment: I.e. if you were to write `printLn (show contents)` on the next line (assuming the type returned by copyFile derives from show) you would get rid of this error as the function would now conform to the expected type `IO`.